# Setup Tomcat to use LDAP user from a specific group

Tags: tomcat, authentication, ldap

I'm setting up a Tomcat 8.5 server to use LDAP authentication for the manager part of Tomcat. So far I have changed the server.xml with the correct realm settings.

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 
                 debug="99"
                 connectionURL="ldap://ldap.server.com:389"
                 authentication="simple"
                 referrals="follow"
                 connectionName="CN=user,OU=Service,OU=Users,DC=server,DC=group,DC=mainserver,DC=com"
                 connectionPassword="password of the user"
                 userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
                 userBase="DC=group,DC=mainserver,DC=com" 
                 userSubtree="true"
                 roleSearch="(member={0})" 
                 roleName="name of the ldap role" 
                 roleSubtree="true"
                 roleBase="OU=Groups,DC=group,DC=mainserver,DC=com"/>
```

Now I want to use a LDAP group to give users access to the tomcat manager/status page. How can I do this? I tried to change the web.xml of the manager to

```
 <security-role>
    <description>
      The role that is required to access the HTML Manager pages
    </description>
    <role-name>LDAP group</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <description>
      The role that is required to access the text Manager pages
    </description>
    <role-name>LDAP group</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <description>
      The role that is required to access the HTML JMX Proxy
    </description>
    <role-name>LDAP group</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <description>
      The role that is required to access to the Manager Status pages
    </description>
    <role-name>LDAP group</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

But didn't work. Login in with a user is possible now but I got the "403 Access Denied" error when I surf to the manager page. Also in the log files of Tomcat there isn't any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed to roleName to the correct role name value in LDAP and after a restart of the tomcat service it is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not Tomcat 8, but the idea is still the same.

This might help:
https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Tomcat%20And%20LDAP